# How to find what version of dawg I have?

Tags: python, import, python-import, dawg

How can I find what version of dwag I have installed in python?  Usually packagename.**version** does the trick, but dawg seems to lack the relevant methods.

Comment: Maybe they named it differently? Try `dir(dawg)` and see what they got?

Comment: It the package was installed with `pip` you can ask `pip list installed`.

Comment: larsks, that answers my question and I could accept that as an answer if you'd care to type it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dawg was installed with pip, the best way to learn what version I have is with `pip list installed`.  (Credit to larsks' comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would go with:

```
print( pack.__version__ )
```

or

```
help( pack )
```

I am wondering if they just didn't include the version yet? The only way I could do it here was with larsks' comment, but that wouldn't work if not installed with pip. Not even the file seems to have the version number:

```
In [30]: dawg.__file__
Out[30]: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dawg.cpython-34m.so'
```